# Z3: Performance of if-then-else vs propositional logic

Tags: performance, z3

In Z3, there are (at least) two ways of expressing if-then-else -- using the `ite` expression, and using propositional logic:

```
(ite X Y Z)

(and (=> X Y) (=> (not X) Z))
```

The drawback of the second expression is that it duplicates `X`. This could dramatically increase the size of the term if `X` is very large (or we have many such expressions). We can mitigate this by introducing a new variable, say `X_is_true`:

```
(and (= X_is_true X) (=> X_is_true Y) (=> (not X_is_true) Z))
```

My question is this: is `ite` essentially syntactic sugar on top of one of these encodings? If not, how does its time/space efficiency compare with these encodings?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is this: is ite essentially syntactic sugar on top of one of these encodings?

In general no. In your example `Y` and `Z` do not need to be of `Bool` sort. For example

```
(declare-fun a () Float64)
(declare-fun b () Float64)
(declare-fun c () Float64)
(declare-fun d () Bool)
(assert (= c (ite d a b)))
(check-sat)
```

Your transformation does not work here because `a` and `b` are of sort `Float64` not `Bool`. Technically your transformation could be applied if the `ite` was hoisted outside the `=` operator like so

```
(declare-fun a () Float64)
(declare-fun b () Float64)
(declare-fun c () Float64)
(declare-fun d () Bool)
(assert (ite d (= c a) (= c b)))
(check-sat)
```

However I'm not sure if such a transformation is always possible and the fact that you will have to sometimes apply semantically preserving transformations means that your transformation is **not** syntatic sugar.

**EDIT**

> how does its time/space efficiency compare with these encodings?

This is difficult to answer because the answer depends on the logic you use and the solving method used. I also don't know enough about Z3's implementation to give you a good answer.

However as a starting point for your investigation you can take a look at what would happen if you tried to apply the Tseitin transform. This is step often used when eagerly transforming a problem to SAT. Note however this is **not** what Z3 will do (it applies its `smt` tactic which works differently).

### Original

```
(declare-const X Bool)
(declare-const Y Bool)
(declare-const Z Bool)
(assert (ite X Y Z))
(apply (and-then tseitin-cnf))
```

Z3 responds with

```
(goals
(goal
  (or (not X) Y)
  (or X Z)
  :precision precise :depth 1)
)
```

### Encoding 1

```
(declare-const X Bool)
(declare-const Y Bool)
(declare-const Z Bool)
(assert (and (=> X Y) (=> (not X) Z)))
(apply (and-then tseitin-cnf))
```

Z3 responds with

```
(goals
(goal
  (or (not X) Y)
  (or X Z)
  :precision precise :depth 2)
)
```

## Encoding 2

```
(declare-const X Bool)
(declare-const Y Bool)
(declare-const Z Bool)
(declare-const X_is_true Bool)
(assert (and (=> X_is_true Y) (=> (not X_is_true) Z)))
(assert (= X X_is_true))
(apply (and-then tseitin-cnf))
```

Z3 responds with

```
(goals
(goal
  (or (not X_is_true) Y)
  (or X_is_true Z)
  (or X (not X_is_true))
  (or (not X) X_is_true)
  :precision precise :depth 2)
)
```